# Compatibility lib for messaging in extensions, Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, promise, firefox-addon

It now seems (nearly) possible to use the same code for an extension in Chrome and Firefox. However when it comes to sending messages between different parts of an extension (popup, content, background) there are still incompatibilities.

Firefox now seems to be a little bit ahead, using the new, suggested, `browser.` namespace, while Chrome uses `chrome.`. Firefox also uses promises, while Chrome here still uses callbacks.

So I am writing functions like this one to get around it:

```
function extTabsSendMessage(tabsId, msg) {
  if (typeof chrome === "undefined") {
    let smRet = browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabsId, msg);
    console("not chrome, smRet", smRet);
    return smRet;
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabsId, msg, function (response) {
        resolve(response);
    })
  });
}
```

I guess someone else must have been doing this already? Is there a compatibility library for this somewhere? Or at least a blogpost which describes the present incompatibilities in this area?

Comment: Simply load and use Mozilla's WebExtension polyfill.

Comment: @wOxxOm Great, thanks! https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you please make it an answer so it becomes more visible to others?